# How can I find the Rect of wrapped text on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, layout, text

Can anybody recommend a good method for determining the Rect of some wrapped text on an iPhone?  I've tried all the built-in methods for NSString in the 2.1 SDK to no avail.  The size methods never return sizes that allow me to completely fit wrapped text in my custom view.

I'm drawing some user customizable text that should always be as big as possible within the limits of my custom view.  If I can determine the rect needed to completely enclose wrapped text for a given max width and font size, I can raise or lower the font size until the text is just big enough to completely fill the custom view without being clipped.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

NSString's sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize: method might be useful:

```
CGSize sizeForText = [theText sizeWithFont:theFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(myMaxWidth, 9999)];
```

You say you've tried all the size methods, but based on your description, it sounds like what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know your view size, call NSString's sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:, starting with your minimum font size, the width of your view, and UILineBreakModeWordWrap.  Then increase the font size until the returned size is as tall as your view.

If you want to set a maximum font size, you could also implement this as a binary search, rather than stepping up the font size.

Answer (score 0):

I found that whenever you set your UITextView's text property, it updates its contentSize property.  That makes it very easy to resize the text view's frame for displaying within a scroll view, etc.